# Missing FilterAttributeFilterProvider in UnityMvcActivator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I am trying to use Unity in an application that was recently upgraded to ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3. I have the Unity and Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC packages installed. In the UnityMvcActivator class, the following line

```
FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
```

is throwing an InvalidOperationException because the collection does not contain a FilterAttributeFilterProvider instance. It contains two filters, GlobalFilterCollection and ControllerInstanceFilterprovider.

I can't reproduce the problem in a new application. I've tried going reviewing the binding redirects and deleting /bin and /obj.

What is wrong? Where is the FilterProviders collection populated?

Answer (score 1):

I sure hope you managed to resolve this in the mean time. But I have this line of code in `UnityWebActivator.Start()`:

```
FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));
```

So I guess that's where it gets added to the Providers collection.

Comment: I gave up and went back to Ninject.